# Deduction of Integer Math (Order of Operations)

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I'm working in Python at the moment, and I'm coming to a problem I don't know where to grab straws. Forgive me if this is covered in some initial Algorithm CS class somewhere, my background is really in Economics. I'm working with financial data, and I know the output and the inputs, I just don't know how to get to the order of operations.

For instance, I have a final price to earnings ratio of 2, but inputs of 10 (price) and 5 (earnings). Just looking at this, I know 10/5 would be equivalent to 2. However, the problem is the order of operations .... this could be either addition, multiplication, division and square roots.

This part seems doable if I just had

```
inputs = [10,5]
output = 2

def deduction_int(inputs, output):
    initial_output = 0
    while initial_output != output:
    try adding, try subtracting (inverse), try dividing(inverse)
```

prints 'yay' when its got itself figured out or if there is an answer

The above code seems obvious and quick, however, when you add 3 variables to it ....

inputs : 10, 5, 7
output : 2.14

and situations such as  (10 + 5) / 7 = 2.14.

I'm stuck with situations where numbers might be run with a different order. For instance 10+5 runs before dividing by 7. Is this a common algorithm type of problem? If so, where exactly do I look for some textbook description (name of the algorithm, textbook)?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't really tell what you are asking here, are you writing a function to evaluate integer expressions? And you want to know the order of operations?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the larger problem? "I'm working with financial data, and I know the output and the inputs, I just don't know how to get to the order of operations." Why are you trying to guess formulas relating input to output? How complicated can the formulas get? What are you doing with the formulas once you figure them out?

Comment: This question might be more suitable for programmers.stackexchange, as it is of a theoretical algorithm, and not a specific programming problem.

Comment: I'm trying to print out how the formula was calculated and print it out. For instance, once I found out the best way to get to 2 was 10 / 5, write a print statement that will say "10 / 5" was the order of operations to get here.

The problem I'm looking at is about 100 outputs and inputs sets (PE Ratios, PS Ratios, stuff like Market Cap), and I'm looking for a systematic way of figuring out how everything was calculated.

Comment: Do your inputs each match to one term in the expression, or can an input come up multiple times? For example if inputs=[2, 3] might the expression be 2*3-2? And are the inputs in the same order as they appear in the expression?

Comment: Hi Trevor, for simplicity, no. I figure if I could figure out where to begin, I could work on that additional component with more time.

Comment: How many inputs are there, and are they all guaranteed to be in the formula?

Comment: A maximum of 4. Given by the amount of comments here, it's apparent that I didn't explain this very well. I'm contemplating deleting this now, as I don't think this is a common algorithm problem and might just require some grit and time.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/jes/cntdn/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a brute-force algorithm.

```
from __future__ import division
import itertools as IT
import operator

opmap = {operator.add: '+',
         operator.mul: '*',
         operator.truediv: '/'}
operators = opmap.keys()

def deduction_int(inputs, output):
    iternums = IT.permutations(inputs, len(inputs))
    iterops = IT.product(operators, repeat=len(inputs)-1)
    for nums, ops in IT.product(iternums, iterops):
        for result, rstr in combine(nums, ops):
            if near(result, output, atol=1e-3):
                return rstr

def combine(nums, ops, astr=''):
    a = nums[0]
    astr = astr if astr else str(a)
    try:
        op = ops[0]
    except IndexError:
        return [(a, astr)]
    # combine a op (...)
    result = []
    for partial_val, partial_str in combine(nums[1:], ops[1:]):
        r = op(a, partial_val)
        if len(nums[1:]) > 1:
            rstr = '{}{}({})'.format(astr, opmap[op], partial_str)
        else:
            rstr = '{}{}{}'.format(astr, opmap[op], partial_str)
        assert near(eval(rstr), r)
        result.append((r, rstr))
    # combine (a op ...)
    b = nums[1]
    astr = '({}{}{})'.format(astr,opmap[op], b)
    for partial_val, partial_str in combine((op(a, b),)+nums[2:], ops[1:],
                                            astr):
        assert near(eval(partial_str), partial_val)
        result.append((partial_val, partial_str))
    return result

def near(a, b, rtol=1e-5, atol=1e-8):
    return abs(a - b) < (atol + rtol * abs(b))

def report(inputs, output):
    rstr = deduction_int(inputs, output)
    return '{} = {}'.format(rstr, output)

print(report([10,5,7], (10+5)/7))
print(report([1,2,3,4], 3/7.))
print(report([1,2,3,4,5], (1+(2/3)*(4-5))))
```

yields

```
(10+5)/7 = 2.14285714286
(1+2)/(3+4) = 0.428571428571
(1+5)/((2+4)*3) = 0.333333333333
```

---

The main idea is to simply enumerate all orderings of the input values, and all orderings of the operators. For example,

```
In [19]: list(IT.permutations([10,5,7], 3))
Out[19]: [(10, 5, 7), (10, 7, 5), (5, 10, 7), (5, 7, 10), (7, 10, 5), (7, 5, 10)]
```

Then you pair each ordering of the input values with each ordering of the operators:

```
In [38]: list(IT.product(iternums, iterops))
Out[38]: 
[((10, 5, 7), (<built-in function add>, <built-in function mul>)),
 ((10, 5, 7), (<built-in function add>, <built-in function truediv>)),
 ((10, 5, 7), (<built-in function mul>, <built-in function add>)),
 ((10, 5, 7), (<built-in function mul>, <built-in function truediv>)),
 ...
```

The `combine` function takes an ordering of the nums and an ordering of the ops, and enumerates all possible groupings of the nums and ops:
In [65]: combine((10, 5, 7), (operator.add, operator.mul))

```
Out[65]: [(45, '10+(5*7)'), (45, '10+((5*7))'), (105, '(10+5)*7'), (105, '((10+5)*7)')]
```

It returns a list of tuples. Each tuple is a 2-tuple consisting of a numerical value and the string representation, `rstr`, of the grouped operations which evaluates to that value.

So, you just loop over every possibility and return the `rstr` which, when evaluated, produces a number close to `output`.

```
for nums, ops in IT.product(iternums, iterops):
    for result, rstr in combine(nums, ops):
        if near(result, output, atol=1e-3):
            return rstr
```

---

**Some useful references:**

- [itertools.permutations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)
- [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)
- [itertools.izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)

Comment: What about `(a+b)*(c+d)`?

Answer (score 1):

So you are given some inputs, and an output, and you want to find the expression that produced it.

The easy way to do this is through brute force, by generating and testing every kind of expression. My program does this by building up big expressions out of simple ones starting with numbers. Over and over it adds on combinations of newly generated expressions with everything before them.

It prints out solutions from simple to complex until it runs out of memory.

```
#!python3

import operator
import decimal
import sys

# Automatically take care of divisions by zero etc
decimal.setcontext(decimal.ExtendedContext)

class Expression(object):
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Number(Expression):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = decimal.Decimal(value)

    def evaluate(self):
        return self.value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

class Addition(Expression):
    def evaluate(self):
        return self.left.evaluate() + self.right.evaluate()

    def __str__(self):
        return "({0} + {1})".format(self.left, self.right)

class Subtraction(Expression):
    def evaluate(self):
        return self.left.evaluate() - self.right.evaluate()

    def __str__(self):
        return "({0} - {1})".format(self.left, self.right)

class Multiplication(Expression):
    def evaluate(self):
        return self.left.evaluate() * self.right.evaluate()

    def __str__(self):
        return "({0} * {1})".format(self.left, self.right)

class Division(Expression):
    def evaluate(self):
        return self.left.evaluate() / self.right.evaluate()

    def __str__(self):
        return "({0} / {1})".format(self.left, self.right)

class Sqrt(Expression):
    def __init__(self, subexp):
        self.subexp = subexp

    def evaluate(self):
        return self.subexp.evaluate().sqrt()

    def __str__(self):
        return "sqrt({0})".format(self.subexp)

def bruteforce(inputs, output, wiggle):
    inputs = [Number(i) for i in inputs]
    output = decimal.Decimal(output)
    wiggle = decimal.Decimal(wiggle)

    expressions = inputs
    generated = inputs

    while True:
        newgenerated = []
        for g in generated:
            for e in expressions:
                newgenerated.extend([
                    Addition(g, e),
                    Subtraction(g, e),
                    Multiplication(g, e),
                    Division(g, e)
                ])
            for e in expressions[0:len(expressions) - len(generated)]:
                # Subtraction and division aren't commutative. This matters
                # when the relation is not symmetric. However it is symmetric
                # for the most recently generated elements, so we don't worry
                # about commutivity for those.
                newgenerated.extend([
                    Division(e, g),
                    Subtraction(e, g)
                ])
        newgenerated.append(Sqrt(g))

        for c in newgenerated:
            if abs(c.evaluate() - output) < decimal.Decimal(.01):
                print(c)
                sys.stdout.flush()

        expressions.extend(newgenerated)
        generated = newgenerated

bruteforce((10, 5, 7), 2.14, .005)
```

Prints

```
((10 + 5) / 7)
((10 - 7) * (5 / 7))
((10 - 7) / (7 / 5))
((10 / 7) + (5 / 7))
((5 + 10) / 7)
((5 / 7) * (10 - 7))
((5 / 7) + (10 / 7))
(sqrt(7) - (5 / 10))
```

None of these evaluate to 2.14 exactly, but they are the same within the "wiggle" of 0.005. To 3 decimal places they're all 2.143 except for the sqrt one which is 2.146.

After generating those it crashes with a MemoryError of course. I don't even want to know the time or space complexity of this :)